# Destruir objetos de un arreglo a otro arreglo UNITY3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estoy haciendo un Spce Invaders, donde tengo distintos tipos de enemigos con sus respectivos colores (verde, amarillo y  azul) Cada 15 segundos se instancia una Nave Enemiga que puede traer alguno de los colores de los enemigos mencionados anteriormente. Si yo destruyo la nave enemiga y es color amarillo, deberían destruirse TODOS los enemigos de color amarillo, y así sucesivamente con los demás colores.

Encontré una pequeña solución y es esta:

Pero mi problema, es que no sé de que forma instanciar la función que lleve ése foreacha, sin tener que usar un update.

¿Alguien se imagina cómo resolver esto de una mejor manera?

¡Cualquier feedback es bienvenido!

```
foreach (var w in invaderList)
{
    var d = invaderList.Find(f => f.tag == "Invader");
    Destroy(w);

}
```

---

Exacto, eso funciona para mi. El tema es CÓMO ejecuto ese método para que recorra toda la lista.

Por ejemplo, si quiero que La Nave Madre, al recibir un disparo, haga el llamado al método para recorrerl la lista y verificar CUAL es el tag que debe eliminar. Pero al hacerlo así, no logra meterse en el foreach. Y cuando quiero hacerlo con una corrutina, me  dice que no puede porque el objeto no esta activo.

**Esto se encuentra en la Nave Madre:**

```
//La nave al impactar con el proyectil del jugador
//llama al método que recorre las listas de los invaders
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "PlayerProjectile")
    {
        m_Boss.DestroyMultipleInv();

        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

**Esto se encuentra en el Manager de la Nave Madre:**

```
 //Recorre la lista y busca por tag
//qué invader destruir
public void DestroyMultipleInv()
{

    foreach (GameObject inv in invaderList)
    {
        if (inv.tag == "Invader")
        {
            Destroy(inv);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A que update hace referencia ? Estas intentando remover de la lista todas las coincidencias segun un determinado filtro ?

Comment: Exacto, si la nave 0 por ejemplo que es el verde, es destruida...todos los aliens verdes debLogré hacer un poco la lógica, pero no sé como ejecutarla para que funcione bien, sin hacer mucho procesamiento. 

  if(bossArr[0] == null)
                foreach (var w in invaderList)
                {
                    var d = invaderList.Find(f => f.tag == "Invader");
                    Destroy(w);
                
                }

Comment: Pero porque aplcias un Find() sobre la lista y el resultado que seria la variable "d" no la utilizas, sino que eliminas "w" que seria cada item de la lista?. el color que mencionas seria el "Invader" que usas de filtro ?  Que funcionalidad realiza el Destroy(), elimina el item de la lista?

Answer (score 1):

No tengo el detalle del metodo `Destroy()` pero imagino esta quitando el elemento de la lista.
El tema es que dentro de un foreach mientras los recorres no puedes alterar la cantidad de items es por eso que se utiliza una lista auxiliar con los datos que queires quitar y luego la recorres.

```
public void DestroyMultipleInv()
{
   var itemEliminar = invaderList.Where(inv=>inv.tag == "Invader");

   foreach (GameObject inv in itemEliminar)
   {
      Destroy(inv);
   }
}
```

En el ejemplo me ayude con linq para hacer mas simple la seleccion, pero si quieres hacer un foreach asignando a una lista temporal puedes hacerlo

Comment: Buena respuesta @Leandro. Pero ¿podrías llevar esto a 1 pregunta y 1 respuesta (siguiendo el  modelo del sitio y no el de otros foros)?

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que `invaderList` es un arreglo (array) de GameObject, es decir, es de tipo `GameObject[]`.

Para destruir todos los objetos que tengan el tag "InvasorAmarillo" hacemos lo siguiente :

```
foreach ( GameObject obj in invaderList )
{
  if ( obj.tag=="InvasorAmarillo" )
  {
    Destroy( obj )
  }
}
```

Esto funciona independientemente de que se ejecute o no en el frame update.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres eliminar de un determinado tipo podrias usar

```
var d = invaderList.Find(f => f.tag == "Invader");

foreach (var item in d){
   Destroy(item);
}
```

Entiendo que filtras en la lista los que quieres eliminar y luego solo es cuestion de recorrerlos invocando al metodo que destruye ese item

Answer (score 0):

Si no quieres usar el update talvez te funcionaria hacer una coroutina, seria algo mas o menos asi:

```
         IEnumerator DestroyMultipleInv(GameObject gameObject)
        {
            foreach (GameObject inv in invaderList)
            {
                if (inv.tag == "Invader")
                {
                    Destroy(inv);

                }
            }
            yield return null;
        }
```

Esta funcion la puedes llamar de la siguiente manera:

```
        public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.tag == "PlayerProjectile")
            {
                m_Boss.DestroyMultipleInv();

                StartCoroutine(DestroyMultipleInv(gameObject));
            }
        }
```